# Nano gallery not found "jQuery(...).nanogallery2 is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with nanogallery does not charge me even though I charge the libraries correctly:

```
    <!-- nano gallery-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  

  <link href="https://unpkg.com/nanogallery2@2.3.0/dist/css/nanogallery2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/nanogallery2@2.3.0/dist/jquery.nanogallery2.min.js"></script>
```

And in console I get the following error:

jQuery(...).nanogallery2 is not a function

Comment: [That code](https://jsbin.com/behekafoyi/1/edit?html,output) doesn't throw that error. You need to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

I could already solve the error, I just had to put the script call at the footer